# Using a C++ iterator to read a list from a file?

Tags: c++, serialization, iterator, boost-iterators

I am trying to read/deserialize a list of elements from a file (and then filter out some of them).   It is a useful approach to use an iterator for this purpose?

My current try is

```
#include <boost/iterator/iterator_adaptor.hpp>
class ReadIterator : public boost::iterator_adaptor<ReadIterator, Elem *, boost::single_pass_traversal_tag>
{
public:
    explicit ReadIterator(const char *filename) : reader(filename)  {}

private:
    friend class boost::iterator_core_access;

    void increment() {
         this->base_reference() = reader.readNext();
    }

    Reader reader;
};
```

This does not properly deallocate memory (e.g., readNew returns a pointer to a new Elem), what is the right way to do this?  Also, how would one actually use such an iterator, how can the end be determined?  Or is there a better approach than using an iterator?

Comment: can you give us sample input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easy way to do this is to use the std::istream_iterator

```
std::vector<YourObjectClass>    data;

std::remove_copy_if(std::istream_iterator<YourObjectClass>(file),
                    std::istream_iterator<YourObjectClass>(),
                    std::back_inserter(data),
                    YourFilter
                   );
```

The standard algorithm copies objects (of type YourObjectClass) from the input `file` and places them into the vector `data` if the filter functor returns true.

The only conditions are:

- YourObjectClass must have an input stream operator
- YourFilter must overload the operator() for objects of YourObjectClass or be a function that takes a parameter of type YourObjectClass.

Simple Working Example:

- My object is a line.
- Filter out line(s) that start with the letter 'A'

Exmpale:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

struct Line
{
    std::string   data;
};
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& stream, Line& line)
{
    return std::getline(stream, line.data);
}
struct AFilter
{
    bool operator()(Line const& line) const
    {
        return line.data.size() > 0 && line.data[0] == 'A';
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::ifstream       file("Plop");
    std::vector<Line>   data;

    std::remove_copy_if(std::istream_iterator<Line>(file),
                        std::istream_iterator<Line>(),
                        std::back_inserter(data),
                        AFilter()
                       );
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks for this elaborate example!  Is there a way to do this when `Line` does not have a default constructor, e.g., if it only has `Line::Line(std::istream &in)`?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than `readNext()` returning a raw pointer to an element, can you construct the call so that it returns a reference-counted smart-pointer that will automatically release it's resources when the reference-count to the pointer goes to zero?  Either that, or you're going to have to find a way to fetch the pointer back so you can call `delete` on it before you allocate more memory via the next call to `readNext()` when `increment()` is called again.

As for the "end", what you could do in this case is have some test in your `Reader` class that detects if you've reached the end of the file or some other ending scenario.  If you have, then return false, otherwise return true.  For example:

```
bool increment()
{
    if (reader.not_end_of_file())
    {
        this->base_reference() = reader.readNext();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

So now you could call `increment()` in some type of loop, and you'll know when you've hit the end-of-file or some other ending because the function will return false.

Answer (score 1):

Using an iterator for the purpose is fine. You haven't given any indication that the existing `istream_iterator` won't work for your purpose though. At least in most cases, you can just write an `operator>>` for a single element, and use `std::istream_iterator` to read a list of those elements from the file.